Number of choices of edges in a regular graph
Let $G = (V, E)$ be an $n$ vertex $d$ regular graph and let $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon'$ be a subset of edges such that
$$\epsilon \subseteq E,~~\epsilon' \not\subset E.$$
Let $(u, w) \in \epsilon$.
Choose two distinct edges $(u_1, w_1)$ and $(u_2, w_2)$ of the graph $H = (V, E \setminus \epsilon)$ such that the six endpoints of the edges, that is $(u, w, u_1, u_2, w_1, w_2)$ are distinct, and in addition, $(w, u_1)$, $(w_1, u_2)$, $(w_2, u)$ are not edges of $G$ and not in $\epsilon'$.
How many choices of $(u_1, w_1)$ and $(u_2, w_2)$ are there?

In this paper, it is mentioned on page $647$ that if $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon'$ are both constant sized, then the number of choices for $(u_1, w_1)$ and $(u_2, w_2)$ are $(n − d)d − \mathcal{O}(1)$.
However, I could not derive this expression and I also wanted a general formula that is a function of the sizes of $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon'$.
Note that there are $nd/2$ edges of $G$. So, the number of distinct choices of $(u_1, w_1)$ and $(u_2, w_2)$ are $\binom{nd/2}{2}$. However, I do not know how to satisfy the other constraints.

There is no general formula; it depends on what $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon'$ are. When the sizes are small, then there's a limit to how much the details can affect the result, and so we get an asymptotic formula. Otherwise, you'd have to look at what the sets are to even be able to say if there are any such choices!

Let $a=|\epsilon|$ and $a'=|\epsilon'|$. Then the graph $H$ has $|E|-|\epsilon|=nd/2-a$ edges. Let $d'$ be the number of edges of $H$, which are adjacent to $(u,w)$. Then $d'\le 2d-2$. There would be $nd-2a-2d'$ choices for $(u_1,w_1)$, but among them are forbidden the choices such that $(w,u_1)\in E\cup \epsilon'$. This condition forbids at most $d-1+a'$ choices of $u_1$ and it forbids additionally at most $(d-1)^2+a'd$ choices of $(u_1,w_1)$.
Then there would be $nd-2a-2d'$ choices for $(u_2,w_2)$, but among them the following are forbidden:

The choices of edges adjacent to $(u_1,w_1)$. This forbids additionally at least two ($(u_1,w_1)$ and $(w_1,u_1)$) and at most $4d-2$ choices (of $(u_2,w_2)$).

The choices such that $(w_1, u_2)\in E\cup \epsilon'$. This forbids at most $d-1+a'$ choices of $u_2$ and it forbids additionally at most $(d-1)^2+a'd$ choices of $(u_2,w_2)$.

The choices such that $(w_2, u)\in E\cup \epsilon'$. This forbids at most $d-1+a'$ choices of $w_2$ and it forbids additionally at most $(d-1)^2+a'd$ choices of $(u_2,w_2)$.



Why is $c \leq 2d - 2$? And why are there $nd - 2a - 2c$ choices of $(u_1, w_1)$? As in, why is there a factor of $2$ multiplied?

Oh, I did not expected so many misprints. I fixed them. I am very sorry for that.
The factor of $2$ came because we distinguish the choices $(u_1,w_1)$ and $(w_1,u_1)$, because, for instance, the condition "$(w, u_1)$, $(w_1, u_2)$, $(w_2, u)$ are not edges of $G$ and not in $\epsilon'$" is sensitive to this distinction.
